# Possible to add youtube title into Wordpress [embed][/embed]?

Tags: wordpress, iframe, youtube, shortcode

I am trying to figure out if it is possible for the [embed][/embed] shortcode feature on Wordpress to display a title within the iframe?

When inspecting the youtube video once it is being displayed on the page, it appears like:

```
<iframe width="940" height="529" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xLZvgt_bPwE?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Would there be a way to edit the embed feature to also include a title (ex: `<iframe width="940" height="529" title="Youtube Video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xLZvgt_bPwE?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>` once it is displayed on the page or post?

Answer (score 1):

If you add this filter and function to your functions.php it should provide your desired result :)

```php
function add_iframe_title($iframe){
    if($iframe)
    {
        $attributes = 'title="Embedded Video"';
        $iframe = str_replace('></iframe>', ' ' . $attributes . '></iframe>', $iframe);

        return $iframe;
    }

    return false;
}

add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'my_embed_oembed_html', 99, 4);
function my_embed_oembed_html($html, $url, $attr, $post_id) {
  if($html)
  {
    return add_iframe_title($html);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this didn't get accepted as the answer. It works perfectly.